# positioning of sub menus in jquery menu combined with stumbleupon toolbar goes wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, positioning

Script Title: dropline menu

Script URL: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/cs...rop_line_menu/

I got the menu working just fine, however, I discovered that when I have the stumble upon toolbar on, the submenu suddenly is placed about 22px lower than it should be. Sometimes this increases to multiple times that difference. You can test out this behavior for yourself in Chrome browser, having the stumbleupon toolbar enabled and hovering over one of the menu items which has a submenu: http://kwestievan.nl/unityexpress/

How can I fix this? I checked if body.offset().top was the problem, but actually that one is higher than the difference: 32px, while the difference in the menu is only 22px.

Comment: How do you turn on the stumbleupon toolbar!

Comment: Ah, it's a Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kcahibnffhnnjcedflmchmokndkjnhpg so you install that one and then turn it on when on the testpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the sub menu is lower beacuse the element

```
<ul class="sub-menu"</ul>
```

is being given a style of

```
position: absolute;
left: 233px;
top: 224px;
```

What this does is place the sub-menu "RELATIVE" to the browser window as such that it is 223px from the left and 224px from the top of the "browser window". This works fine when there is no "stumbleupon" toolbar. However when you do add the stumbleupon toolbar, it adds the toolbar in the form of a iframe element. The height of the iframe element than causes the sub-menu to be pushed down since the dimensions of the browser window have changed.

You can quickly test this by finding out the height of the "stumbleupon" toolbar and than comparing that height to the amount of distance the sub-menu has pushed down on you monitor/screen resolution. They will be same.

The solution is to give the element

```
<li id="menu-item-1738"</li>
```

a style of

```
position: relative;
```

and than style the sub-menu so that it aligns and is "absolutely" positioned "RELATIVE" to the containing li element. For example

```
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 15px;
```

Offcourse all this is being done by your script. I am not sure why are you using javascript for this. This can be easily acheived by CSS alone.